# Wrapping instance variables in accessor methods

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, attr-accessor

Sandy Metz says (POODR book, page 26):

> Because it is possible to wrap every instance variable in a method and to therefore treat any variable as if it's just another object, the distinction between data and a regular object begins to disappear.

I am not sure if I understand what she is explaining. When we define the accessors, we are wrapping the instance variables (data) on a method but methods are not objects. So what does she mean when she says that we can treat variables as if they're just another object?

Comment: It doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The primary difference between data and objects is behaviour. Objects can modify their internal state without changing their interfaces, while data are static structures.

When we wrap data access within a method, we get the same benefits of an object - the interface remains static to consumers even if the underlying data structure needs to change.